# Exporting Excel Sheet data to SPSS Syntax format (.sps) using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spss

I need to export an output sheet to *.sps (SPSS Syntax) format.

The code I use works 80% of the time:

```
Sub Print_CM_to_sps()
Dim FSO As Object
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  
  If FSO.FileExists(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\All_CM_Edits.sps") Then
    Set LogData = FSO.OpenTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\All_CM_Edits.sps", 2, True)
    LogData.Close
    Set LogDatas = FSO.OpenTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\All_CM_Edits.sps", 8, True)
    For i = 2 To lstRow
        LogDatas.WriteLine ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i).value
    Next i
  Else
    Set NewFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\All_CM_Edits.sps", 8, True)
    For i = 2 To lstRow
        NewFile.WriteLine ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i).value
    Next i
  End If
End Sub
```

I am confused why 20% of the time my created *.sps file is not readable by SPSS.

When such anomaly occurs, the *.sps file can be properly viewed with any other editing tools (e.g. notepad/npp/sublime/UE/etc.) but when opened in IBM SPSS Statistics it is only read as one line of Chinese characters.

To give an example, these are the lines that are contained in my *.sps file:

> Rename Variables (AU3a01 = AU3a_1). Rename Variables (AU3a02 =
> AU3a_2). Rename Variables (AU3a03 = AU3a_3). Rename Variables (AU3a04
> = AU3a_4). Rename Variables (AU3a05 = AU3a_5). Rename Variables (AU3a06 = AU3a_6). Variable Labels AU3a_1 "Brand A". Variable Labels
> AU3a_2 "Brand B". Variable Labels AU3a_3 "Brand C". Variable Labels
> AU3a_4 "Brand D". Variable Labels AU3a_5 "Brand E". Variable Labels
> AU3a_6 "Brand F". Value Labels /AU3a_1 to AU3a_6 1 "1 - Terrible" 2
> "2" 3 "3" 4 "4" 5 "5" 6 "6" 7 "7" 8 "8" 9 "9" 10 "10 - Perfect".
> Execute.

**SPSS Error Display**
[image]

Comment: Since later in the process you are going to use SPSS syntax, you could consider automating this syntax production in SPSS instead of VBA (can be done easily)

Answer (score 1):

k, thanks for promptly answering.

Did a deeper dig and came with a solution that involves enabling library references as the attached image. It is done by going to Tools>>References in the module editing window.

[image]

Oddly enough, I have been searching for solutions for 3 weeks now and luckily came across this solution just today. :)